# What's the simplest way to log a single field from a set of structs?

Tags: go

Let's say I have a func that takes in a slice of Person:

```
type Person struct {
    ID              uuid.UUID   
    FirstName       string
    LastName        string
    ... plus 20 more fields
}
```

When logging I might want to log just the ID. Is there a simple way to do this without creating another type? I'm using [Logrus](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus). If I was in JS I'd just use the map function. Example logger line:

`logger.Debugf("personProcessor starting for people: %v", persons)`

But this will result in a lot of unnecessary output in my logs. The ID is enough to find the person we are processing.

Comment: I don't think there's a builtin for that, so you'll have to write it yourself. You may use reflection so it'll work on all struct types.

Comment: Often times "what's the simplest way in Go" questions are really asking "is there a shorter solution than a for loop", to which the answer is often "no, or put the for loop in a function of you don't want to see it".  I'm not sure of that's the case here, but as an experienced programmer you probably won't have much trouble implementing this in a for loop.

Comment: Right, I mean I'm sure I can do it but I don't want to add 3+ lines of code just to make debug logging look better. I don't like that tradeoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the reflect package to write a "generic" function for extracting the fields:

```
func extractField(s interface{}, name string) []interface{} {
    var result []interface{}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        result = append(result, reflect.Indirect(v.Index(i)).FieldByName(name).Interface())
    }
    return result
}
```

Use it like this:

```
logger.Debugf("personProcessor starting for people: %v", extractField(persons, "ID"))
```

[Run an example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7YZihlFqJE1)

The function can be extended to included formatting bells and whistles:

```
// sprintFields prints the field name in slice of struct s 
// using the specified format.
func sprintFields(s interface{}, name string, sep string, format string) string {
    var fields []string
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        fields = append(fields, 
            fmt.Sprintf(format,
                reflect.Indirect(v.Index(i)).FieldByName(name).Interface()))
    }
    return strings.Join(fields, sep)
}
```

[Try it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5IPDrf0N26J)!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Logrus, but this works with the standard library:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strconv"
)

type Person struct {
   ID int
   FirstName, LastName string
}

func (p Person) String() string {
   return strconv.Itoa(p.ID)
}

func main() {
   p := Person{9, "First", "Last"}
   fmt.Println(p) // 9
}
```

Comment: Works, but should be noted that you won't have the option to print different fields in different location as the type can only have one `String()` method.

Answer (score 0):

See this function that uses reflect and string building:

```golang
func printPersonField(persons []Person, field string) {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    fmt.Fprintf(buf, "Persons (%s): [", field)
    for i := range persons {
        if i > 0 {
            fmt.Fprint(buf, ", ")
        }
        fmt.Fprint(buf, reflect.ValueOf(persons[i]).FieldByName(field).Interface())
    }
    fmt.Fprint(buf, "]")
    log.Println(buf.String())
}
```

Usage like so:

```golang
func main() {
    persons := []Person{
        {1, "first1", "last1"},
        {2, "first2", "last2"},
        {3, "first3", "last3"},
    }
    
    printPersonField(persons, "ID")
    printPersonField(persons, "FirstName")
    printPersonField(persons, "LastName")
    
}
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Persons (ID): [1, 2, 3]
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Persons (FirstName): [first1, first2, first3]
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Persons (LastName): [last1, last2, last3]
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lM-6bYbqEgg)

Note that this isn't "generic", as in it won't work for any type.  It strictly takes a `[]Person` input. If you want to make it work for other types of slices of other structs, then see I Love Reflection's answer.